# Android Opencv setup with android

Tags: android, opencv

> I am trying to setup my android project with androidX with opencv

---

I have tried many solution from stackoverflow infact all of them in 14 hours but no progress

---

**Main Error of All time**

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve project :openCVLibrary414.

---

[image: app.gradle]
[image: Error]

> My app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shakira.lane"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation ':openCVLibrary441'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle of your openCVLibrary414? How did you import this module?

Comment: i was following this tutorial for latest androidx https://medium.com/@kashafahmed/a-proper-beginners-guide-to-installing-opencv-android-in-android-studio-updated-5fe7f3399e1c

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle of your openCVLibrary414?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greeting Ahmed 
              i know you are having difficulty but use [quickbirdstudios](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android) android library.